# How would I secure a php code?

Tags: php, file, upload

How would I secure this code???

The problem is that you can use ../ to move back directories. How would I lock the directory?

```
<?php
    $target_path = "user/";
    $username = basename( $_POST['user'] );
    $file = basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
    $target_path = $target_path . $username
    $target_path = $target_path . "/"
    $target_path = $target_path . $file
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " has been uploaded";
?>
<br />
<?php
    echo "The file can be opened or downloaded at asasse.no-ip.org/user/" . $_POST['user'] . "/" . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
    } else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: put the uploaded images on a different machine, within a non-executable file system. Oh and don't just check the extension of files. You should decode the binary and check for a magic value or something if you are uploading images.

Comment: You shouldn't use unfiltered user input (such as $_POST). Strip the offending characters from the username before you use it.

Comment: The goal of this script is to allow a user to upload any file they like.

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "Strip the offending characters from the username" ? And how should I go about doing that.

Comment: By far the easiest way is to use basname( $filename ); http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php , pathinfo(); is another http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: Couldn't I just use $Target_path = str_replace ("..", ".", $Target_path); Sorry I am still unsure about many php concepts.

Comment: @AnthonySasse - only if you are worried about downward movement in the directory tree, what of the filename "/folder/filename.ext", this would place the file inside "folder" if it existed, granted less of a problem, but this is what basename() etc are for.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I changed the code. I wanted to know if it is now secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, use

```
$file = "../libs/somebadfile.php"
$file = basename( $file );
//outputs "somebadfile.php"
```

or

```
$path_parts= pathinfo( $file );

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; 

//outputs 
//=========
// "../libs"  - not sure about this can't test it right now ;-p
// "somebadfile.php"   ~ equivalent to basename() above.
// "php"
// "somebadfile"
```

Then you supply the base path, only allowing the user to supply the filename part.

```
"path/to/folder" . $file;
```

And no more directory traversal.  This is also known as a "dot-dot-slash" attack.  From wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack

It's better more "secure" now but It could be cleaned up a bit more:

```
$basepath = "user/";
$username = basename( $_POST['user'] ) . "/";
$filename = basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
$filepath = $basepath . $username . $filename;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $filepath)) {
    echo "The file can be opened or downloaded at asasse.no-ip.org/$filepath";
}else{
    echo "There was an error uploading file \"$filename\", please try again!";
}
```

If you want to only allow files of a specific set of extension, such as images.

```
$basepath = "user/";
$username = basename( $_POST['user'] ) . "/";
$allowed = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp' );
if( !preg_match( "/\.(".implode("|", $allowed).")$/i", $filename, $extension ) ){
    echo 'Extension "'.$extension[1].'" not allowed, must be one of the following "'.implode('", "', $allowed).'" file types.';
}else{
    $filename = basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
    $filepath = $basepath . $username . $filename;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $filepath)) {
        echo "The file can be opened or downloaded at asasse.no-ip.org/".$filepath;
    }else{
        echo "There was an error uploading file \"$filename\", please try again!";
    }
}
```

P.S I haven't tested this but it should be pretty close.

Comment: So would this be a better approach

Comment: LoL - a down vote for using the correct function?  - @AnthonySasse - give it a try and see.